# XNA C# Find max number in an integer

Tags: c#, xna

I currently have an integer that changes according to where an object is on the screen. After the object has moved I would like to find what the max number in the integer was. (In essence, after making my character jump, I want to find the max height of that jump). How would I go about doing this? Could I use something like Math.Max ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the integer gets overwritten every time, you'll have to intercept the event in some way. I assume an event gets fired when his position changes?

In that case you can just hold a temporary field `private int highest;` Whenever the position change event is fired, check if the current height is more or less than the value of `highest`. If it is more, change the value of `highest` to the current height.

In the end you will remain with the highest value.